# Executing CLI commands from Java

Tags: java, command-line

I have this API - which I managed to carryout some API steps solely from the CLI without using their GUI.
Now I need to execute these CLI commands (i.e. for carrying out these API steps) in Java.
When surfing, I couldn't find a helpful link for sample code on how to deal with this.
May I know how to execute CLI commands using Java code (say in a Java class)

Appreciate any insight, suggestions or guidance.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute commands like that:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<put command here>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) - or, the older alternative, the several `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` methods.